# Way to update record with Entity Framework via ViewModel

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Look at this entity and his associated view-model class:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Here is what I used to do when I want to update a record:

```
var jack = MyDbContext.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id=2);
jack.Name = "New name";
MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It works great !

Now, I am wondering how I should do the same thing when working with the viewmodel:

```
var all = MyDbContext.MyEntity.Select(e => new MyViewModel
  {
    Id = e.Id,
    Name = e.Name,
    ...
  };
// Let's suppose I have a grid with all records.
// User may click on one record in order to see the details
var jackvm = all[1];  // For example jack !
jackvm.Name = "New Name";
```

At this step, I can't call SaveChanges because jackvm is not an attached entity. It is a viewmodel instance.
Here is what I saw on a project and I want to know if it is a good practice to work like that:

```
  var jackEntity = new MyEntity { Id = jackvm.Id, Name = jackvm.Name, ... };
  MyDbContext.Entry(jackEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
  MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see, an entity is created from the viewmodel's instance values. Then, this entity is attached to the dbcontext. SaveChanges will update the record in the database. My first question is What do you think of this pattern ? Is it a good practice ?

I have a second question: I need to log every write operation. I have override SaveChanges in order to track changes, this way:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{    
  foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
  {
     if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.OriginalValues.GetValue<String>("Name"));        
        Console.WriteLine(entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<String>("Name"));        
     }
  }
  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

It works great with my first example.
But for the second example, OrignalValues contains the new value !
How can I do, in this case, to get the original value for name field ?
Please not I want to avoid to make a select query.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked Automapper?

Comment: Yes, but automapper is just an helper which avoid lines. Same result

Answer (score 0):

No, that pattern is not recommended for updates. For simple scenarios where your entity and view model have a one-to-one relationship with *all* columns it can work fine, but as soon as you move to a more complex entity it falls apart. Take for example an entity like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

and a ViewModel

```
[Serializable]
public class PersonSummaryVm
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public int Age => DateTime.Now.Subtract(DoB).TotalYears;
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

For the sake of argument this view model is a projection where we want to display their age rather than their DoB, and we flatten down the address. Say we have an operation where a user can update some of their details. Even the above is a very simple example, but imagine an entity with 50+ columns and relationships. We could pass back a PersonSummaryVm, or we could pass back something like an UpdatePersonVm with just the values we want to update, or if we just wanted an UpdatePersonName method, we could just pass the PersonId and Name to the function.

Let's use that last example to demonstrate some of the problems with this approach, these issues would apply regardless of what view model or fields you pass unless you pass *everything*.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdatePersonName(int personId, string name)
{
    try
    {
        var person = new Person { PersonId = personId, Name = name };
        _context.Attach(person);
        _context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(ActionResponse.Success()); // Return ActionResult or View etc.
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         var logId = Logger.LogException(ex, personId);
         return Json(ActionResponse.Failure($"Person could not be updated due to an error. (Ref #{logId})"));
      }
}
```

The code will generally execute, but there are several significant problems here.

1. There is no verification that a Person record with that personId actually exists, or that it is in a state that should allow editing.
2. When we create a new Person object, the DoB will default to a DateTime.Min() (1/1/0001) and the address reference will be null. When we save that Person, values will be overwritten because we didn't populate them so EF treats the partially populated entity as what the current state should be.

Even if you use a view model that has the same fields as the entity you expose problems:

1. You are passing more data to and from your view/consumer than that view will probably ever need, or they should even see.
2. Because you are passing back every field from the view/consumer, even if you only displayed some of the fields and allowed them to edit some of the fields, the rest of the data is visible and tamper-able by anyone with a browser debugger running.
3. There is no detection or protection for stale data overwrites. Has the data changed since this consumer retrieved the source data you are proposing to update?
4. As your system evolves and you add new properties and relationships to your entities, your view models can fall out of sync. The view doesn't necessarily need to display the new data/relationships, but your update method will now only copy the data it knows about, leaving you with a situation where data gets wiped, meaning expanding the view model and data over the wire just to satisfy the update scenario.

The better approach would be to fetch your entity verify the edit is valid and update the values.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdatePersonName(UpdatePersonVm personVm)
{
    try
    {
        if ( personVm == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("personVm");

        var person = _context.Persons.Single(x => x.PersonId == personVm.PersonId);
        if (personVm.RowVersion != person.RowVersion)
            return Json(ActionResponse.StaleUpdate(Mapper.Map<PersonSummaryVm>(person)));

        person.Name = personVm.Name;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(ActionResponse.Success(Mapper.Map<PersonSummaryVm>(person))); // Return ActionResult or View etc.
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         var logId = Logger.LogException(ex, personId);
         return Json(ActionResponse.Failure($"Person could not be updated due to an error. (Ref #{logId})"));
      }
}
```

Using this approach you verify that the Person actually exists. Which could opt to do a `SingleOrDefault` to present a nicer failure message to the consumer if the person was not found. Both the entity/table and view model can contain a RowVersion stamp that updates automatically as the row is updated. When we fetched the VM passed to the client to update it would have a particular RowVersion, that user might spend 10 minutes making changes before posting the Update action, in which time someone else might have updated it. We can compare the row versions and handle a scenario where they might be overwriting something that has changed. Now because we have loaded an entity, we can copy over just the values expected to have changed and EF will generate an `UPDATE` statement for those modified values only if any of them actually changed. We can use Automapper's `Map<TSource,TDestination>` here to assist with that.

i.e.

```
Mapper.Map(personVm, person);
```

... to save on manually copying values across. If using Automapper it is impotant ***not*** to use the default map call:

```
person = Mapper.Map(personVm);
```

This would set 'person' to a new reference to a Person entity which isn't attached to the DbContext.

Automapper can help when reading the data via the `ProjectTo<TDestination>()` method which takes the place of using `Select()`. This helps build efficient queries:

```
var personVm = context.Persons
    .Where(x => x.PersonId == personId)
    .ProjectTo<PersonSummaryVm>(config)
    .Single();
```

where the passed mapper config contains the configuration on how to map the entity to the view model. For instance flattening the Address, rather than:

```
var personVm = context.Persons
    .Where(x => x.PersonId == personId)
    .Select(x => new PersonSummaryVm
    {
        PersonId = x.PersonId,
        Name = x.Name,
        DoB = x.DoB,
        Address = x.Address.AddressLine1 + ", " + x.Address.City
        RowVersion = x.RowVersion
    }).Single();
```

Another performance pitfall /w Automapper would be trying to use `Map()` within a `Select()`:

```
var personVm = context.Persons
    .Where(x => x.PersonId == personId)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => Mapper.Map<PersonSummaryVm>(x))
    .Single();
```

The problem with using `.Map()` is that it cannot be translated down to SQL so you need to put the `ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` ahead of the Select, and then in the above case because Mapper will want to resolve properties from Address we would be triggering a lazy load on Address, or have to remember to eager load Person.Address. Even in that case the Select will be loading *all* properties from the Person and referenced entities that Map would need to touch before mapping our VM, where `ProjectTo` will be able to compose down just the required fields in the resulting SQL.

So Automapper does a bit more than just reducing the lines of code. It's well worth the time to get familiar with.